# Como saber si un registro existe

Tags: vb6

Trabajo con vb6 y sql server, necesito saber si un registro existe para eso tengo una clase para conectarme a la base de datos.

```
Public cn As ADODB.Connection
Public rs As ADODB.Record

Public Sub Conectar()
  Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
  rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
'  cn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=gestvehicular;User=root;Password=123456;Option=3;"
  cn.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=.;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
End Sub

Public Sub Desconectar()
  On Local Error Resume Next
  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
  cn.Close
  Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Tengo creada una Function en la cual le paso el parámetro id de tipo integer para poder hacer esta consulta a la base de datos

```
Public Function Existe(id As Integer) As Boolean


On Error GoTo tratarError
  Dim cmd As New Command
  Conectar
  With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cn
    .CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID=@id"
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .NamedParameters = True
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@id", adInteger, adParamInput, , id)
    .Execute
    If (rs.EOF) Then

  End With
  On Error GoTo 0
  Desconectar
  Exit Function
tratarError:
  MsgBox Err.Description
End Function
```

Con la consulta sql que tengo me si existe en la base de datos me da 1 y si no existe me da 0 entonces lo que quiero hacer es que si me da 1 que retorne `true` y si da 0 que retorne `false` no se como hacer eso con ADO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los problemas que encuentro en tu función son los siguientes:

- La falta de inicialización del recordset `rs` mediante `Set rs = .Execute`
- Y la falta de tratamiento del retorno para devolver `True` o `False` mediante la función ternaria [`iif(rs.Fields(0) > 0, True, False)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d(v=vs.90).aspx)

.

```
Public Function Existe(id As Integer) As Boolean

On Error GoTo tratarError

    Dim cmd As New Command
    Dim Existe as Boolean
    Conectar
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = cn
        .CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID=@id"
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .NamedParameters = True
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@id", adInteger, adParamInput, , id)

        Set rs = .Execute
        Existe = iif(rs.Fields(0) > 0, True, False)
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Desconectar
    return Existe
    Exit Function

tratarError:
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Function
```

Lo siguiente que mejoraría en tu consulta y que te sugiero que uses como una buena práctica es reemplazar el uso del `COUNT()` por el uso de la función [`EXISTS()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql), en consultas dónde la existencia se determina sobre un solo registro cómo imagino que es tu caso, la mejora es mínima, pero dónde es más notable, es cuando el `COUNT()` puede llegar a contar múltiples registros,  eso se debe, contado en una forma poco académica, a que el `EXISTS` solo necesita saber que hay al menos una fila para devolver un Verdadero, en cambio el `COUNT()` obviamente requiere "leer" todas para devolver la cantidad. Hay bastante material sobre está práctica, te sugiero si quieres profundizar leas [esto](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2007/12/15/exists-vs-count-the-battle-never-ends.aspx). Habría que hacer algunas modificaciones a tu rutina. Por un lado el `SELECT` sería así:

```
.CommandText = "SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID=@id) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END"
```

Y el control del retorno para determinar la existencia sería:

```
Existe = iif(rs.Fields(0) = 1, True, False)
```

Comment: no entiendo porque complejizaste tanto el codigo que tenia OP. Su Recordset se iba a llenar si encontraba algo, y no se iba a llenar si no encontraba nada. Entonces que sentido hacer un query con un case para terminar haciendo el mismo iif al final?

Comment: Por que le quise sugerir una buena práctica de SQL que es reemplazar el `COUNT` por el `EXISTS`. Pero entiendo tu punto, le edito la respuesta para que al menos tenga las dos opciones.

Comment: no deja de hacer un barrido de toda la tabla o el indice (bah si tiene indice lo cuenta directo). en este caso no entiendo el sentido, salvo que le expliques a OP la diferencia entre COUNT y EXISTS. y porque seria una buena practica.

Comment: Te parece trivial esa diferencia? Entiendo sí que es un tema secundario a la pregunta, así que como te decía editaré la respuesta para no confundir al op.

Comment: Hola Patricio, gracias por responder toda mi vida lo había hecho con COUNT pero voy a investigar que PRO y CONTRAS tendría con lo que me recomiendas.

Comment: Existe = iff(rs.Fields(0) > 0, True, False) Fields no definido

Comment: Revisa el código de mi respuesta, lo acabo de editar se me había escapado dos `execute`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Muchas gracias.